# Table won't show using jquery sheetrock

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins, sheetrock

Hi I'm trying to show the table from Google Spreadsheet using the jquery plugin Sheetrock. It shows fine when I did it in jsfiddle, but it doesn't show when load on an html. Here's the code:

```
!DOCTYPE html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/dist/jquery.sheetrock.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/sheetrock.css">
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var mySpreadsheet = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AlRp2ieP7izLdGFNOERTZW0xLVpROFc3X3FJQ2tSb2c#gid=0';

            $('#statistics').sheetrock({url: mySpreadsheet});
        });
        </script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>table</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="statistics" class="table table-condensed table-striped"></table>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Shouldn't your !DOCTYPE html have <> around it?

Comment: I have a feeling @clayperez gave you the correct advice. Pretty sure your !DOCTYPE html needs <> around it, as everything else looks good.

Answer (score 0):

"jquery.sheetrock.min.js" library did not get proper path. May be that's why, it's not showing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-sheetrock/1.0.0/dist/sheetrock.min.js'></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/sheetrock.css">
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var mySpreadsheet = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AlRp2ieP7izLdGFNOERTZW0xLVpROFc3X3FJQ2tSb2c#gid=0';

            $('#statistics').sheetrock({url: mySpreadsheet});
        });
        </script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>table</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="statistics" class="table table-condensed table-striped"></table>
    </body>
</html>
```